# Submitting apps for facebook app review

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-3.0

I want to submit my app to the facebook for review.
I try to run with this command from terminal:

```
xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator7.1
```

result:

```
CompileC build/...\ ....build/Release-iphonesimulator/.../Objects-normal/i386/FeedbackViewController.o .../FeedbackViewController.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

I can build the app successfully if I run using armv7 architecture instead of i386, but my app get rejected. Any idea?
(`xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator7.1` (build successfully, but get rejected by facebook).

Comment: what message do u get from facebook?

Comment: this is not the error "xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator7.1" this is used for find the simulator type, check that u get the permission is correctly and the correct place

Comment: I got it fixed, the problem is we cannot use certain 3rd party framework or new framework in XCode because we should use i386 to build the project in order to submit to facebook. @Indrajeet the message from facebook is the app cannot be built in their side.